# Iterate through rows and insert data in temp table - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, loops, iteration

I have some data as follows

```
Duration        Start Date
==========================
2               11/11/2014
1               11/6/2014
3               11/22/2014
```

I want to iterate to all the above three rows and produce an output as follows

```
Date
===========
11/11/2014
11/12/2014
11/6/2014
11/22/2014
11/23/2014
11/24/2014
```

Take the start date increment the date by duration and create separate rows for each dates

Comment: There a number of ways to do this, which have you tried?

Comment: Honestly, I tried using loops and CTE but to no avail; am new to SQL so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't iterate but use set based approaches like ...

```
WITH Nums AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT Value = number 
    FROM master..[spt_values] 
)
SELECT Date = DATEADD(d, n.Value - 1, t.[Start Date])
FROM Nums n CROSS JOIN TableName t
WHERE n.Value BETWEEN 1 AND t.Duration
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e37e6/1/0)

Note that this approach works only until 2,164.  Another approach is to use a number-table. Read:

http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1

If you want to insert it into another table you can use it in this way:

```
WITH Nums AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT Value = number 
    FROM master..[spt_values] 
)
INSERT INTO #TempTable ([Date]) 
SELECT Date = DATEADD(d, n.Value - 1, t.[Start Date])
FROM Nums n CROSS JOIN TableName t
WHERE n.Value BETWEEN 1 AND t.Duration
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, let me try this.